# How to learn visitor location rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Ruby on Rails 4.0.1.

I development link short service so I need to find my users' locations. For example UK, Turkey, Belgium.

How can I do this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GeoCoder Gem. It allows you to find a user's location.

> > Geocoder is a complete geocoding solution for Ruby. With Rails it adds geocoding (by street or IP address), reverse geocoding (find street address based on given coordinates), and distance queries. It's as simple as calling geocode on your objects, and then using a scope like Venue.near("Billings, MT").

[GeoCoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the data from http://www.ip2nation.com to find the country of a visitor from it's IP address. From this site you can download a file to create and populate a table `ip2nation`. I next created a model for this type:

```
require 'ipaddr'    

# 2 columns: ip and country
class Ip2nation < ActiveRecord::Base  
  self.table_name = 'ip2nation'
  self.primary_key = :ip

  #-------------  Finder

  # Get the country code for the given ip string
  def self.find_country(ip)

    # Convert the ip to a number
    ip_number = IPAddr.new(ip).to_i

    # Find the country in the database
    where('ip < ?', ip_number).order(:ip).pluck(:country).last     
  end 
end
```

And use it like this:

```
country = Ip2nation.find_country(request.remote_ip)
```